# Same Date stamp not equal in swift?

Tags: swift

EDIT: thanks to  Alexander - Reinstate Monica. See the link in the comments for more info.

I ran into something odd today.  I'm using firebase storage for an app and I want to compare the date of the file on the server with the one stored locally which I have manually set the attributes for when creating the file.  If the dates are different then the app will re-load the file from the server like so:

```
 if localModDate != serverModDate { 
 //re-download file
 }
```

most of the time this works correctly, but sometimes the if statement get triggered even though the dates match (checked via print statements) and if I convert the stamps to strings then the dates always match correctly:

```
 if String(describing: localModDate) != String(describing: serverModDate) { 
 //re-download file
 }
```

my guess is that swift is converting to epoch time (I tested this and the epoch times are indeed off in like the 6th decimal place).  Is this correct or is there something else going on here?

Comment: Don't look for exact matches. Check if the dates are within some acceptable threshold of each other

Comment: `Date` is just a `TimeInterval` (which is a typealias for `Double`) of elapsed seconds since Jan 1 2001. The [`==` operator](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/2195121bf063e2db7c71080fcae7e76e8a43950e/Foundation/Date.swift#L156-L158) just compares those two `Double`s, so it's subject to the same floating point precision issues of regular `Double`s.

Comment: thanks that's what I figured was happening, but just wanted to know for my own info.

Comment: For anyone else interested this is not just a swift issue but a product of the way floating points are represented in memory. see https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/ for more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date is just a `TimeInterval` (which is a `typealias` for `Double`) of elapsed seconds since the "reference date" (Jan 1 2001). The [`==` operator](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/2195121bf063e2db7c71080fcae7e76e8a43950e/Foundation/Date.swift#L156-L158) just compares those two `Double`s, so it's subject to the same floating point precision issues of regular `Double`s.

Use [`Calendar.isDate(_:equalTo:toGranularity:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292870-isdate) to check if the dates are "close enough":

```
if Calendar.current.isDate(localModDate, equalTo: serverModDate, toGranularity: .second) {
  ...
}
```