# Why not work == between two similar dates

Tags: swift, date, comparison, equality

I'm trying to compare dates in Swift being exactly the same (at least apparently) and it doesn't recognize the if ==

```
let fecha1 = unFT[0].fechaCreacionUnFT!
let fecha2 = unFT[1].fechaCreacionUnFT!
            
print("fecha 1:",fecha1)
print("fecha 2:",fecha2)

if fecha1 == fecha2 { 
    print("Bingo!!!")
} else {
    print("Did not match")
}
```

Getting this output:

> ---fecha 1: 2021-04-13 10:10:14 +0000
>
> ---fecha 2: 2021-04-13 10:10:14 +0000

Comment: That means the dates are not identical, dates have a sub-second resolution. Try `print(fecha1. timeIntervalSince(fecha2))` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59106815/1187415

Comment: @MartinR clicked on that link, read the answer, thought it was pretty well written and in my style... oh look, that’s me! It’s a strange feeling to run into your own answers haha

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Same Date stamp not equal in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59106815/same-date-stamp-not-equal-in-swift)